# How to read a text(.txt) file in python line by line with delimiters without pandas?

Tags: python, text-files, file-handling, data-extraction

I have a text file with about 2113 lines in which data is is stored in the format `string:integer` and I need to store both the string and the integers as an array in variables `status` and `next_move`. I have done it with pandas but I want to find a way to do it without using pandas.

**The data file is as follows:**

```
.....
OOXXX O X:5
OOXXX OX :5
OOXXXO  X:6
OOXXXO X :6
OOXXXOOXX:None
OOXXO  XX:5
OOXXO X X:7
OOXXO XX :8
OOXXOX X :8
OOXXOXX  :7
....
```

**The code I used with pandas is this :**

```
  df = pd.read_csv("Dataset.txt", sep=":", names=['strings', 'moves'])
    a = df[['strings']]
    b = df[['moves']]
    status = a.to_numpy()
    next_move = b.to_numpy()
    status = status.flatten()
    next_move = next_move.flatten()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use csv library.

```
status = []
next_move = []
with open("Dataset.txt") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=":")
    for row in csv_reader:
        status.append(row[0])
        next_move.append(row[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `genfromtxt` in numpy.

So an example would be:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
my_data = genfromtxt("Dataset.txt", delimiter=";")
```

Note that my_data is a numpy array and can be indexed/spliced normally.